# Is concrete noun member of abstract noun

Tags: nouns

I think normally concrete noun is member of abstract noun (membership in set theory), but it is not always true. For example, "Socrates" is a person, but it is not member of mankind (abstract noun). "Socrates" is member of "all men". Is "all men" also abstract noun?

Comment: BTW, how do I use latex on this site? It looks like $\in$ is not working

Comment: Why do you call human being an abstract noun? Abstract nouns are non-physical things like happiness and democracy.

Comment: *Humanness* is an abstract noun. I'm not sure about *mankind* - it could be used abstractly, or concretely as a group noun for all human beings. *Human being* definitely isn't abstract.

Comment: How are you distinguishing *mankind* from *all men*, and why is Socrates only a member of the second?

Comment: That is why I ask the question. I want to know what is consensus of this in linguistics now. I believe, by Aristotle's principle that sum of all parts is always less than the whole, which means sum of all concrete realizations of abstract noun is always less than abstract noun itself. So "all men" is less than mankind. But I want to see if this is known in linguistics now.

Comment: You might be better off asking at [philosophy.se]. You sound like you're taking a philosophical approach to it, not a linguistic approach. Summing nouns and "less than mankind" don't make sense linguistically.

Comment: I wouldn't say normally. Those are just two derivational suffixes which can be used to make abstract nouns, but there are other suffixes, and many bare abstract nouns.

Comment: “concrete noun is member of abstract noun” - What makes you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete nouns and abstract nouns do not intersect (unless polysemous).  They are a binary division of nouns (dividing 'things' into physical and non-physical).  'Mankind' and 'men' are concrete nouns.

Comment: I thought "mankind" is abstract noun because it is not ordinary men but possess all features of men. Maybe abstract of concept and abstract noun are different thing.

Comment: 'Mankind' consists of those *ordinary* men, but it is possible that a noun can be in both categories (but not at the same time) -- that's what I meant by *polysemous*.

Comment: "Mankind" includes all humans and so should be considered as abstraction of men. So abstraction of concept could be different from abstract noun, that is what I mean.

Comment: @MathWizard The abstract noun for the abstraction of human and all features of humans is humanness.